# Process Modelling and Process Development perspective not visible in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, process, modeling

In Eclipse Neon 3, the Process development and process modelling perspectives are not available. How to add these perspectives?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Remember this is a volunteer platform. If someone knows the answer, and they have the time, they will post an answer. Chasing for an answer does not usually help. While you wait, do persist with reading the documentation or otherwise researching the problem.